# Verify a CMS message with the Firefox Add-On SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, signature, pki

How can I verify the signature of a message following the CMS structure  (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) by using the Firefox Add-On SDK?

I already could find some classes (e.g. http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla/html/interfacensICMSMessage.html), but I'm unsure if I can use them in an Add-On as there is not very much documentation.

If this is not possible, is there at least a way to check if the given certificate of the message is trusted by the list of CAs built into Firefox? (I'll try to use the webcrypto API to verify the signature in this case)

Comment: WebCrypto is the most idiotic standard around. It seems well specified, but it completely skips the part on how the script itself is secured, which key stores are available and even which (base set of ) algorithms needs to be defined. Because of all of this it hasn't seem much traction (and I thank all the developers for flat-out ignoring the API in the first place).

Comment: In this case the WebCrypto API would make sense and I don't need to store private keys. I just need to verify a signature with the public key. Essentially I just need to decrpyt a signature with the public key and then compare two hashes.

Comment: If you could somehow trust that public key. But that's not defined.